# Как вызвать оператор перегруженной функции ввода/вывода в наследуемом классе?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

```
 class Tarray
{
public:
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, Tarray& B);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Tarray &B);
};

class ExtraTarray : public Tarray
{ 
public :       
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, ExtraTarray& B){
         std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, const Tarray& B);  
         };         
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const ExtraTarray &B){
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Tarray& B);
    return out;
    };
};
     istream& operator>> (istream &in, Tarray& B){

            int n;
            n = B.max ;   
            B.mas = new double [n] ;
            for(int i=0;i<B.max;i++){
            cout<<"Введите "<<i+1<<" элемент массива"<<endl;
            in>>B.mas[i];
            }
            return in;}
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Tarray &B)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<B.max;i++)
        {
            cout<<B.mas[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
            return out;
        }
```

1. Почему функция ввода в поток не просит возвращать что-то при переопределении в классе наследника, а функция вывода просит?
2. При вызове функции вывода компилятор просто автоматом пропускает строчку с вызовом дружественной функции и сразу идет на возвращение. В итоге функция не выводит ничего.
3. Какой правильный синтаксис вызов перегруженного оператора в классе наследнике?
   В простом случае можно было не переопределять функции ввода/вывода для класса наследника, потому что они наследуются, но именно здесь это требуется в явном виде.

Comment: `<<` и `>>` - это не операторы ввода-вывода. В каком учебнике вы прочитали эту чушь? Это операторы битового сдвига. Просто для потоков они переопределены так.

Comment: "функция ввода в поток" - ввод и вывод всегда относительно памяти, поэтому ввод из потока и вывод в поток.

Comment: @Герман Борисов, а как вы называете эти функции?..  Начнем с того, что  << и >> не являются операторами вообше, они являются лексическими токенами. Для битовых операций они используются для определения оператора сдвига, а для потоков они служат для 
определения операторов  ввода/вывода, просто потому что более подходящие лексические токены. Сами операторы являются операторами потокового ввод/вывода , иначе их не назовешь, кроме как функциями...

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/cpp-built-in-operators-precedence-and-associativity?view=vs-2019 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/ Везде это называется именно "оператором битового сдвига". Для встроенных типов оператор `<<` выполняет то, что определено стандартом. Для классов - вызывает метод или функцию с названием `operator<<`. А вот уже перегруженный метод класса `ostream` выполняет вывод в поток. `<<` - оператор. `ostream::operator<<` - функция вывода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перво-наперво, в вашем коде нет никакого "переопределения в классе" и никакого фактического "наследования". Friend-функции, объявленные в классе, не являются методами класса, а являются самостоятельными свободными функциями. К ним не применимо ни "переопределение", ни "наследование".

1. Не ясно, о чем вы говорите. Кто "просит"? Все функции у вас объявлены с возвращаемым значением. Значит возвращать что-то нужно из всех из них.
2. Где этот вызов? Если речь идет о

   ```
   std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, const Tarray& B);
   ```

   то это никакой не вызов вообще. Это объявление функции. Зачем вы написали объявление функции, если хотели сделать вызов?
3. Синтаксис самый обыкновенный: либо операторная запись, либо функциональная

   ```
   ExtraTarray e;
   std::cout << e;
   operator <<(std::cout, e);
   ```

   В вашем случае по-видимому нужно что-то вроде

   ```
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &in, ExtraTarray &B)
    {
      return in >> static_cast<Tarray &>(B);
    }
   ```